# Why would one want to initialize static members in a static constructor instead of the static fields with initializers in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, static, initialization

Why would one want to initialize static members in a static constructor instead of the static fields with initializers in C#?

I frequently see something like this:

```
public static class AgeProvider
{
    static ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields> table;
    static AgeProvider()
    {
        table = new ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields>();
    }
    private sealed class Fields
    {
        internal DateTime BirthDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Is it in any way better than this:

```
public static class AgeProvider
{
    static ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields> table = new ConditionalWeakTable<MAgeProvider, Fields>();
    private sealed class Fields
    {
        internal DateTime BirthDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

Maybe there is some kind of a performance difference? The example above is from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b942f9/how-to-create-mixin-using-C-Sharp-4-0/).

Comment: For your specific example, I wouldn't use a static ctor, although the end result is near enough identical. However sometimes your initialization is more complex, and so a static ctor is required. Note that defining a static ctor (even if it's empty) can change when your class is initialized, [see the `beforefieldinit` flag](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/BeforeFieldInit)

Comment: Just one example - let's say you have a coding standard that says fields must be defined in alphabetical order. Then you can get into situations like https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5QoHV whereby the result is not what you expect. Move those assignments into the static constructor, and all is well. _Just one example._